# How do I extract named groups with unknown order with a regular expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Let's say I want to extract `foo\d{2}` and `bar\d{2}` as named groups (say, `foo` and `bar`) from strings that might contain one or two of them in any order, e.g.:

```
hello foo33 world bar12
bar66 something foo14
this one only has bar45
this one has neither
```

Is there a way to do it in with a single regular expression in Java?

It would be best if the solution could be generalised to 3+ named groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`(foo|bar)\\d{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/4Vu9HH/1) with `find` method to get all required values

`(foo|bar)\\d{2}` either match `foo`

- `|bar` : or `bar`
- `\\d{2}` : match exactly 2 digits

Code

```
    String s="hello foo33 world bar12\n"+
            "bar66 something foo14\n"+
            "this one only has bar45\n"+
            "this one has neither";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(foo|bar)\\d{2}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

output :

```
foo33
bar12
bar66
foo14
bar45
```

Comment: Haha, good job, we came to the same conclusion!  I was halfway through writing my answer when yours showed up :P

Comment: @AaronN.Brock it happens sometimes :)

Comment: It seems I've oversimplified my situation. Your answer does address the question that was actually asked, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the regex or operator: `|`

In this case, you want to find `foo` *or* `bar`.  So all you need to do is group them with the *or operator*.

```
(foo|bar)\\d{2}
```

[Here's an example on regexer!](http://regexr.com/3fknf)